# C++ templates, partial specialization and friends

Tags: c++, templates

I am having trouble getting a class to be friend with a template and all its partial specializations. Is there any specific trick to achieve this or some limitation I am not aware of?

Comment: Can you provide some code (a reduced test case) you are trying to fix?

Comment: Your questions tend to be very vague. Try to ask more concrete questions; Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Y{
  template<class T>
  friend class X; // friends all instantiation forms of X

  void a_private_func() const{}
};

template<class T>
class X{
public:
  void f(Y const& y){ y.a_private_func(); }
};

template<class T>
class X<T*>{
public:
  void g(Y const& y){ y.a_private_func(); }
};
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/gmJGE)